# How to solve $\int_{-1}^{1} (x^{4/3} + 4x^{1/3}) dx$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I started by integrating it this way:

$$(\frac{3}{7} x^{7/3} + \frac{16}{4}x^{4/3})$$

What is wrong with it?

Comment: What's wrong with it is that it is a definite integral and you just calculated the indefinite integral.  You now have to plug in $1$ and $-1$ and subtract to get the final answer.

Comment: @GregoryGrant The OP stated "I started by ..."  There is nothing wrong with the start.

Comment: Hint: $3 \times 4=12$!  so your $16/4$ is wrong  :)

Comment: I took it to mean what should they do next.  But if they simply want to know if that's the anti-derivative, then obviously the answer is "nothing".

Comment: use that $\int x^{n}dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$ if $n\ne -1$

Comment: If I replace x by -1 I'd have $\sqrt[3]{-1^7}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> $\frac{6}{7}$

Integrating,

> $ \int^1_{-1} x^{4/3} 4 x^{1/3} \,dx = (\frac{3}{7}x^{7/3} + 3 x^{4/3})^{1}_{-1} = \frac{3}{7} + 3 + \frac{3}{7} - 3 = \frac{6}{7}. $

In the OP as it reads now, it appears that you increased the power on the second term and *multiplied* by the new power instead of *dividing*.

Answer (score 1):

Simple way for me is to split the integral up and look at in that respect.
$\int_{-1}^{1} x^{4/3} + 4x^{1/3}dx=\int x^{4/3}dx + \int 4x^{1/3}dx = \frac{6}{7} + 0 = \frac{6}{7}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for the indefinite integral we get $$3/7\,{x}^{4/3} \left( x+7 \right)$$

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand how you got this

Answer (score 0):

You are asking "What is wrong with it?"

$$(\frac{3}{7} x^{7/3} + \frac{16}{4}x^{4/3})$$

Check the derivative

$$(\frac{3}{7}\frac{7}{3} x^{4/3} + \color{red}{\frac{16}{4}\frac{4}{3}}x^{1/3}).$$

Comment: Ironically, the error in the coefficient of the second term is harmless as the term vanishes anyway.